# How to extra description fields in Jenkins plugin to the job configuration?

Tags: java, plugins, configuration, jenkins, jobs

I'm looking to write a plugin that would allow me to add extra fields to the job configuration.  Currently the job configuration page allows a user to enter a description. What I would like to do is to add some required fields for a job and validate it with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [tutorial on writing a Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial), it's pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this tutorial is basic build and deploy information. I guess I really need is a knowledge of the extension points and how I can overload the job config